# Intel Edison Code and Power Issue

Tags: intel-edison

I want to run my Edison on a power from the jack, but every time I remove the USBs it stops the execution of the code that is on there. Nor will it power back up with the code. Any ideas why this would happen? The code doesn't depend on a connection to the computer.

Comment: Just curious, how do you know it stops the execution, is it performing some I/O on the GPIO pins and that stops?

Comment: I cant actually say for sure, it does stop I/O. Any time I re-power the board it wont do anything with the code or not that I can tell. This has never happened to me before.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out every body is having this problem with the latest version of the OS (Yocto 2.1). Only real fix is to downgrade.